# Prove that {$g^n|g \in G$} is a subgroup of G. Prove that this is not necessarily the case if G is not commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a commutative group, let $n>0$ be an integer. Prove that {$g^n|g \in G$} is a subgroup of $G$. Prove that this is not necessarily the case if $G$ is not commutative.

Can someone guide me with this problem?

Comment: Do you know what a subgroup is? What goes when you go and try to verify that this is a subgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H = \{g^n | g \in G\}$ then if $h \in H$ then $h = g^n$ and $h^{-1} = (g^{-1})^n$ so $h^{-1} \in H$. So you just need to show that $H$ is closed under multiplication. For this show $(h_1 h_2)^n = h_1^n h_2^n$ by commutatvity. To show that commutativity is required, take $G$ to be a permutation group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that this subset is closed under multiplication (the group operation), i.e. that the product of two $n$th powers is itself an $n$th power. You will need the commutativity for that.